# WPF BackgroundWorker exception message display

Tags: wpf

Whenever my BackgroundWorker throws an exception, I'd like to get just the exception message that I threw. But Instead I get a bunch of lines like

```
System.Exception : System.Exception : Message
at WPFApp_Desktop
at ...
at ...
```

How can I eliminate all this and just get the exception message I send?

It doesnt make sense for me to parse the output and split it because I'm catching exceptions across the app in the DispatcherUnhandledException function and the format of exceptions may vary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Exception.Message` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message.aspx), not the [`Exception.ToString` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring.aspx), to get just the message without the full call stack.

You may also want to log `ex.GetType().ToString()` (assuming `ex` is your `Exception` object) to display the exception type, and/or log `ex.InnerException` (repeatedly) to display any nested exceptions.